# How to share folder between Host and Docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I created a C# dotnet core 2.1 code that will be running in a Docker to list files in the Docker app folder.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("listing...");
        foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        }
    }
}
```

I am running on Docker Desktop (Community) on a Windows 10 machine and the image is created as below:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build

WORKDIR /app  
COPY ConsoleApp6/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish/ .  

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp6.dll"]
```

When I simply run the docker I get the result as below:

[image: Docker run]

Now what I want to do is mounting a folder to the Docker while the code is running. I create a folder `c:\data` on the host machine, which has a single file named `test.txt` and I run below command:

```
docker run -v c:\data:c:\app test
```

but I get the error below:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ConsoleApp6.dll"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are mounting volume with docker you are overriding the directory, not adding to it. so when doing `-v c:\data:c:\app` you hidden from your container all your application files inside `/app` and left with only the files that exists in the host's `c:\data` directory

**Possible Solution**
Create entrypoint script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Copy all from /temp to /app
cp /temp/* /app
dotnet ConsoleApp6.dll
```

then mount the host folder to temp:

```
docker run -v c:\data:c:\temp test
```

Comment: Thanks, so how to add new set of files to the `app` folder?

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly. you can create an entrypoint script, mount the `c:\data` to another folder inside the container like `/temp` and inside the entrypoint script copy all files from `/temp` to `/app`

Comment: Would that be the only way to share a file between host and container?

Comment: yes, to share files you must use volumes. if the data is permanent you can just copy it inside the image.

Comment: I updated the entry point in the Dockerfile as `ENTRYPOINT ["cp", "/temp/*", "/app"]`  and then `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/ConsoleApp6.dll"]`. I do not get the error, but still cannot see `test.txt` in the result of the list.

Comment: you can't have more than one `ENTRYPOINT` only the last will run

Comment: I created an `entry.sh` which simply just dose the `dotnet /app/ConsoleApp6.dll` and I `ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entry.sh"]` in the Dockerfile. Now I get error `failure in a Windows system call: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (0xb7)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193852/discussion-between-arash-aghlara-and-matanper).

Comment: Thanks, managed to make it working. I change it to .bat and did ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entry.bat"] which does copy all files from `temp` to `app` folder.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows as a host and Linux as a guest, use `-v /c/somewhere/on/windows:/somewhere/on/linux` minding the leading lower case `/c/`.